# the file created with the jarbundler from a jar has different behavior than the source jar

Tags: osx-yosemite, jarbundler

I create an mac app file from a jar using the jarbundler 2.3. 
 i am having the following issue:

- when you access the application from the jar directly, it opens a
  specific folder placed near the jar file, in the same folder with the
  jar  file

but

- when you will access the application from the .app file created with the jarbundler from the jar file above, it
  will open the mac user home folder instead of the folder opened by the above jar file

Ca you tell me what should I do to have the same behavior for the both files,the .jar file and .app file created with jarbundler 2.3 from the .jar file.?

The jar bundler that I used is located here:https://github.com/tenny1028/JarBundler/releases/tag/v2.3
and I followed the steps from this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxxnAGlHtrE to create .app files from the .jar files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest release of JarBundler has an option to do this.

You can view it here: https://github.com/tenny1028/JarBundler/releases/tag/v2.4